# SQL Server Agent job for LinkedServer

Tags: sql-server

has anybody seen this error before?  I have a job running on server A against linked server B.  However linked server B is also server A.

The job didn't complete successfully for the second times in a row.

The error message is:

> TCP Provider: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network
>   address/port) is normally permitted. Error 10048 OLEDB provider
>   SQLNCL11 for linked server HJEAST returned messgae "Login timeout
>   expired" error 7412 OLE DB provider "SQLNCL11" for linked server
>   returned message "A network related or instance specific error has
>   occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
>   found or not accessable.  Check if instance name is connect and SQL
>   server is configured to allow remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue with the port which is used here as it is already in use by some other program. Kindly try below:

1. Start CMD and typed in : netstat -a
2. Check Local Address column and corresponding port Most likely port will be already active( in use ) in another program.
3. Change the port to a different port(In case of   SQL Server, you can specify multiple ports and you may choose different one for linked server)

you may find more details on the similar issue at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836209/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address-port-is-normall).

Hope above helps.

Comment: Thanks. This morning this job started successfully. What port being used here? Port 1433?
How do I find out what port this SQL agent job is using? Also the name of the other program that is using it?

Comment: The above comment is from the OP (forgot to log in)

Comment: Please check this link --> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/

Comment: For finding program name and listening port together, you may use netstat -a -b

Comment: This morning this job failed again, also I find the same time another Symentic Antivirus Job was running:

Answer (score 0):

This morning this job failed again, also I find the same time another Symentic Antivirus Job was running: Scan type: Tamper Protection Scan
Event: Tamper Protection Detection
Security risk detected: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMC\UNISPHERE HOST AGENT\HOSTAGENT.EXE
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\14.0.2415.0200.105\Bin\ccSvcHst.exe
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\14.0.2415.0200.105\Bin
Computer: AEROHJSQCLU01SR
User: SYSTEM
Action taken: Access denied
Date found: Monday, December 09, 2019  6:40:09 PM  Were they related?  Do you think symentic software blocked the port used by SQL Server?

Comment: Do you think port 1433 on the linked server is being blocked?  The linked server happened to be the same server it sits on.